# Request validation (size or digits) failing after removing a dash from an number-only zip-like input

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-validation

I have a brazilian zip code that I have to validate. I am using input mask to make it better looking and validating in JS.
 This is the format: `99999-999`. So 5 digits, a dash, then 3 digits.

Then I have a form request to validate the input. If I dump the input before doing anything, it is correct:  `"zip" => "80980-980"`. I can validate this using regex: `"zip" => 'regex:/[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{3}/',`, but I don't think it is correct.

So I am removing the dash:

```
$this->merge(['zip' => str_replace('-', '', $this->get('zip')) ]);
```

If I dump the input, it is correct once again:  `"zip" => "80980980"`.

Here's the form request:

```
class AddressCreateRequest extends Request {

public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

public function rules()
{
    $this->merge(['zip' => str_replace('-', '', $this->get('zip')) ]);

    //dd($this->all());

    return [
        ...
       "zip"       => "required|digits:8",
        //"zip" => 'regex:/[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{3}/',
       ...
    ];
}
```

}

But if I try to validate this using `size:8` I get this: `The zip must be 8 characters.`, even though the input is `"zip" => "80980980"`.

If I try using `digits:8` I get `The zip must be 8 digits.`, input is `"zip" => "80980980"` again.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Size doesn't work beacuse Validator think that you try to check a number, so `size:8` it's check for number 8, you could cast your variable to string or
use regex

Comment: What about the `digits:8` rule?